# Does ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in MySQL cause extra disk space to be used?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, on-duplicate-key

We have a large table (around 100 million rows) that is often written to, and often updated rapidly (think an app that auto-saves state every x seconds).

All writes to this table currently do INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, since it's an easy way to ensure we make an insert when we need to, and an update if the row already exists. Very few other write operations are done on the table (very few DELETEs, for example).

However, we have noticed that this seems to grow the table more than it should. For example, in production this table is currently around 700GB on disk (the size of the ibdata file), but if we dump the SQL and import it in a fresh database, the ibdata file for the table ends up around ~70GB.

Is this a side effect of using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE? Or is this caused by something else? Has anyone else noticed this effect?

This is all running on MySQL 8.

Comment: *Is this a side effect of using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?* No. *is this caused by something else?* Of course. Investigate RM about InnoDB on-disk structures, especially about freed/unused space in pages. Also read about OPTIMIZE TABLE statement.

Comment: It is normal for `ibdata` files to grow uncontrollably. They never return disk space to the operating system, even when you reorganize the tables. You should use separate files per table, then you can reclaim the space with reorganization. Sadly even after you do this you can never get the `ibdata` space back without reinstalling MySQL.